# How to partition Spark dataset using a field from Kafka input

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka

I have a Spark application that reads data from a Kafka topic. My code is -

```
val df = spark.readStream
 .format("kafka")
 .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "server1")
 .option("subscribe", "topic1")
 .load()
df.printSchema()
```

This yields

```
root
 |-- key: binary (nullable = true)
 |-- value: binary (nullable = true)
 |-- topic: string (nullable = true)
 |-- partition: integer (nullable = true)
```

I need to

1. query for both the `key` and `value`
2. deserialize the binary key to a string
3. deserialize the binary value to an object (I have a deserializer for this)
4. repartition the input tuples/DataSet based on the key string from step 2

Would the code below be the correct way to do it?

```
val dataset = spark.readStream
     .format("kafka")
     .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "server1")
     .option("subscribe", "topic1")
     .load()
     .select($"key", $"value")
     .selectExpr("CAST(key as STRING) AS partitionId", "value AS value")
     .repartition(col("partitionId"))
     .mapPartitions{row => createOutputMessages()}
```

It does run fine, but I have no way to know if the partitioning was done correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get an idea about how your dataset is partitioned by using built-in function [`spark_partition_id()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/sql/index.html#spark_partition_id). So, something like this will show key distribution across Spark partitions:

```
dataset.groupBy(spark_partition_id,$"partitionId").count.show(false)
```

Comment: I tried to do this before the `dataset.writeStream` line, but got `Queries with streaming sources must be executed with writeStream.start();`. So I put the line after `dataset.writeStream`, but then got `org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.UnsupportedOperationChecker$.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$analysis$UnsupportedOperationChecker$$throwError`. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I didnt realize its DStreams that only have `repartition(numer_partitions)`, not repartition by column.